# How to store the .dat file name in the table using SQL Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have hundreds of data files that all have the same structure and all need to be loaded into the same table.  However, there is an extra column called "filename" in the table, and I am supposed to store the name of the .dat file the data was loaded from in there.

I know I could create a separate control file for each .dat file but that is a pain to do.  Can anyone suggest a better way or how to generate the control files from a list of dat files?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest thing is to use a single control file that does not populate the filename column, and after loading each file use SQLPlus to execute an update like:

```
UPDATE table SET filename='&1' WHERE filename IS NULL;
```

So each new set of rows is loaded with a NULL value for filename, then you update all the rows that have NULL to the current filename.

Comment: Rather than update, before the load you could do an ALTER TABLE MODIFY COLUMN filename DEFAULT 'xxxx';

Answer (score 0):

There's a chunk of code [here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1905875�) for deriving CTL files, but it sort of depends on your OS.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd `dirname $0`

file=`ls -rt fullpathofmyfileindir/*.csv | tail -1`
filename=`basename $file`
f=`echo $filename | cut -c 9-16`

cat LOAD_0.CTL > $1.ctl
echo $1
echo 'NOTIF_FILE_DATE "TO_DATE('\'$f\'','\'YYYYMMDD\'')",' >> $1.ctl
echo 'FILE_NAME CONSTANT '$1',' >> $1.ctl
echo 'NOTIF_ID "NOTIF_SEQ.NEXTVAL")' >> $1.ctl
sqlldr migration9c/migration@AXOT01 control=$1.ctl log=$1.log data=$1
rm $1.ctl
```